# How to show a Browser Popup on tab closing without page interactions and if the popup cancel button clicked how to redirect to another URL?

Tags: javascript, dom, popup, window, onbeforeunload

I have triggered a popup to show on tab close, the popup works fine if I at least click on somewhere of the page, otherwise the popup doesn't appear a the tab closes.
other thing is if I choose not to leave and pressed cancel button, I want to redirect to a different URL, Is that possible to Perform ?

Below is the code I'm using to show the popup.
I'm using HTML JAVASCRIPT PHP for this project.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to leave the page?")) {
      return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    consoile.log('Cancel');
  }
};
```